# Can I download an app's xcappdata folder from the command line?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to look at the database from my iPhone app.

I can download the app's xcappdata folder from Xcode's organizer, but I'd really prefer to do this from the command line so that the entire process could be automated.

The database needs to be pulled from an actual iPhone, not the emulator. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Apple does not allow you to pull data from the iPhone, as one could simply pull keychain files or personal data off the phone a decrypt it. If you want, however, you could jailbreak the iPhone, download OpenSSH from Cydia, and SSH onto the phone to download the file. I do not endorse the second method; it is only if you really want the file.

I think I understand your question correctly, but tell me if I'm wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The app in question is one I'm developing and the database is within the app's sandbox, so I have the ability to download the files I want. The only issue is that I have to do it through Xcode's GUI and I'd rather do it from the command line.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I'm not quite sure how you would go about doing that, but good luck.